# How to resolve error while installing thrift-0.8.0 on ubuntu

Tags: thrift

```
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c thrift /usr/local/bin/thrift
/usr/bin/install: cannot remove '/usr/local/bin/thrift': Permission denied
make[3]: *** [install-binPROGRAMS] Error 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I was tempted to make my answer as short as your question:

```
sudo make install
```

But then I thought, it could be worth mentioning that [the 0.9.3 release of Apache Thrift](https://thrift.apache.org/download) just happened a few days ago. The 0.8.0 release is compatible so it is perfectly fine to stay with it, but in the meantime a lot of improvements (and bug fixes) happened so you may want to try a more current version.